# Why cant I register a HttpRequestHandlerServlet via @Bean annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I am currently using SpringBoot and a `@Configuration` JavaClass to register the Servlet `HttpRequestHandlerService`

But It always tells me that is is not available

Here is my code Class for the registration of the bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final String SERVLET_NAME = "DataFileServlet";

    /**
     * Initializer servlet context initializer.
     *
     * @return the servlet context initializer
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer initializer() {
        return servletContext -> {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD", "1");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "admin");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", "true");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader", "false");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE", "url");
        };
    }

    /**
     * Is used to register the servlet HttpRequestHandler.
     *
     * @return the servlet "registartionBean"
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpRequestHandlerServlet> dataFileServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<HttpRequestHandlerServlet> registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new HttpRequestHandlerServlet());
        registrationBean.setName(SERVLET_NAME);
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    /**
     * Is responcable for registering a filter.
     *
     * @return the filter "registrationBean"
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter> encodingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        registrationBean.setEnabled(true);
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("encoding","UTF-8" );
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        return registrationBean;
    }
    /**
     * Is resposible for registering a new listener.
     *
     * @return the listener "registrationBean"
     */
    @Bean ServletListenerRegistrationBean<IntrospectorCleanupListener> IntrospectorCleanupListener(){
        ServletListenerRegistrationBean<IntrospectorCleanupListener> registrationBean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setListener(new IntrospectorCleanupListener());
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```

and here is my Stacktrace

```
2019-02-14 16:16:35.151 ERROR 5468 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'DataFileServlet' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.init(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:974)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:83)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2897)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at de.Application.main(Application.java:33)

2019-02-14 16:16:35.233  INFO 5468 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-14 16:16:35.234 ERROR 5468 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at de.Application.main(Application.java:33)

2019-02-14 16:16:35.244  INFO 5468 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-14 16:16:35.309 ERROR 5468 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'DataFileServlet' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'DataFileServlet' in your configuration.
```

And my WebXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>admin</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- security: don´t send x-powered-by-header -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
        <param-value>url</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DataFileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DataFileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DataFileServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

What Can I do to get It to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpRequestHandlerServlet` delegates to an `HttpRequestHandler` bean. This is described in the class's javadoc:

> delegates to an `HttpRequestHandler` bean defined in Spring's root web application context. The target bean name must match the `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` servlet-name

When defining the registration bean for the servlet you have set its name to `DataFileServlet`. As a result, when the servlet receives a request, it is attempting to retrieve a bean named `DataFileServlet`. This is failing as there is no bean defined with that name.

To use `HttpRequestHandlerServlet` as you have configured it, you need to define an `HttpRequestHandler` bean named `DataFileServlet`:

```
@Bean(name="DataFileServlet")
public HttpRequestHandler dataFileServlet() {
    return (request, response) -> {
        // Handler implementation
    };
}
```